# Rails help clockwork error: Exception NameError -> uninitialized constant Delayed::Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

When I run my clockwork I get this error:

```
C:\Rails\konkurranceportalen>bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
Starting clock for 1 events: [ statistik ]
Triggering statistik
Exception NameError -> uninitialized constant Delayed::Job
   lib/clock.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:27:in `c
all'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:27:in `r
un'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:96:in `b
lock in tick'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:94:in `e
ach'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:94:in `t
ick'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:80:in `b
lock in run'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:79:in `l
oop'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:79:in `r
un'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/bin/clockwork:20:in `<top
 (required)>'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/clockwork:19:in `load'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/clockwork:19:in `<main>'
```

My clock.rb in lib folder:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'clockwork'
include Clockwork

every(2.minutes, 'statistik') { Delayed::Job.enqueue(Scraper.new) }
```

I have changed my clock.rb to:

```
require 'clockwork'
require 'delayed_job'
include Clockwork

every(2.minutes, 'statistik') { Delayed::Job.enqueue(Scraper.new)
```

Then I get this error:

```
C:\Rails\konkurranceportalen>bundle exec clockwork lib/clock.rb
Starting clock for 1 events: [ statistik ]
Triggering statistik
Exception NameError -> uninitialized constant Delayed::Job
   lib/clock.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:27:in `c
all'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:27:in `r
un'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:96:in `b
lock in tick'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:94:in `e
ach'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:94:in `t
ick'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:80:in `b
lock in run'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:79:in `l
oop'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/lib/clockwork.rb:79:in `r
un'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/clockwork-0.2.3/bin/clockwork:20:in `<top
 (required)>'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/clockwork:19:in `load'
   C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/bin/clockwork:19:in `<main>'
```

My scraper.rb in lib folder:

```
class Scraper
require 'mechanize'
def iqmedier
    #SOME CODE

  end

def mikkelsen
#SOME CODE

   end
def orville
   #SOME CODE
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not actually familiar with ClockWork, but don't you need to add a "require 'delayed_job'" at the top of clock.rb?  You may also need to install the delayed_job gem.

That said, if you're running with 'bundle exec', you ought to be using a Gemfile to manage this, and you shouldn't be requiring rubygems in clock.rb.

Comment: I have updated my question with new error log. I have installed delayed_job and run the migration

Comment: How should I run my clock.rb file?